# Convert DataFrame encoding from latin-1 to utf-8 python.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have an csv with spanish characters so to overcome encoding issues with utf-8, I used
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding = 'latin-1')
However, in next steps I am unable to apply charmap to the records as it required data in utf-8 format only.

Is there a way to read dataframe in latin-1 encoding then convert it back to utf-8

Comment: Try `encoding='latin_1'` (instead of `latin-1`) [standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings#:~:text=latin_1,Western%20Europe)

Comment: @im0j tried with latin_1 as well, but same issue persist